# Talend open studio send gmail mail

Tags: smtp, gmail, talend

my job contains a simple tSendMailCompenent 
the configuration are as follow:
smtp host =  smtp.gmail.com
smtp port = 465
beside the user name, email to, ...
also, I have allowed a less secure app for the Gmail account sending

the problem is after I run the job, the Talend hang up the job is running forever

[image]

Comment: do you have any firewall or similar which is blocking your access from talend server to gmail smtp

Comment: @garpitmzn  the firewall is disabled

Comment: can you show us the Component tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen this component hang. It usually returns quickly if there is an issue.

Have you tried creating a simple Job with just the component so that you can establish that it is this component, on it's own, at fault?